# How to make a ROS topic?

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, topic, create, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I make a ROS topic. I want to make a ROS topic (Either a subscriber or a publisher) which I can either write to or read from.
For example: how ROS programs have topics I can subscribe to or publish on. I want to make my own.
I just want to be able to send a float32 type message using a ROS command on my topic.
Is this possible to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284976/how-to-make-a-ros-topic?/) by [sdcguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/33652/sdcguy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-03-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Of course. You can do that. First I would reccomend you to follow ROS [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29). Also, you can use your own message types. Follow ROS message [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv).

You can create your own topics using ROS messages. Also, you can create different topics using same message type.  If you need, you can create your own message type as well.

You always subscribe topics published by a subscriber. Not messages. To do that,

1. You should create a publisher that publishes topics like chatter.
2. Then, you should create a subscriber that can subscribe that specific topic that is published by the publisher.

whenever the subscriber receives topics, your callback function in the subscriber node is called. Then you can use those data.

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdcguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/33652/sdcguy/) on 2018-03-09**:
Thanks for the response.
The first tutorial you have mentioned is a tutorial to write a publisher, which publishes on the topic "chatter". It is making a call to the advertise function which "notifies anyone that is trying to subscribe to that topic".

**Comment by [sdcguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/33652/sdcguy/) on 2018-03-09**:
So, should I make a subscriber for that topic? And that is basically me creating my own topic.

**Comment by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) on 2018-03-10**:
Hi sdcguy, I just updated the answer with a breif explanation. Hope this will help you.